# Point'n'Print setup in Windows 7 x64 on Samba server

Tags: windows-7, samba, drivers, network-printer

I've done a Point'n'Click setup on Samba/CUPS for Windows 7 Clients.

The following things are done:

## CUPS

Activated Raw printing support by `dpkg-reconfigure cups`

## SAMBA

Added to the *smb.conf* the following lines:

```
[global]
[…]
    load printers = yes
    printing = cups
    printcap name = cups
[…]

[printers]
        comment = all printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        browsable = yes
        guest ok = no
        writable = no
        printable = yes
        create mode = 0700
        write list = @admin root

[print$]
        comment = Driver
        path = /etc/samba/drivers 
        browsable = yes
        guest ok = no
        read only = yes
        write list = root, @admin
```

And I've added the group admin to the windows printer admins with:

`net rpc rights grant admin SePrintOperatorPrivilege -U <hostname>/root`

## Windows 7 Driver uploading

Here is the point where I got stuck. I uploaded the x86 driver for my Dell MFP Laser 3115cn within the *server properties* of the samba-server successfully. But I am unable to associate the driver with my printer. I've gone to

1. *settings* of the printer
2. clicked *no*
3. selected the *advanced* tab
4. started the wizard by clicking *new driver*

At this point windows says to me, that there are **no drivers found for that device**. What when possibly at this point? The System is, as mentioned before, an Windows 7 x64.